# LinkedIn JavaScript SDK - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

Tags: javascript, sdk, linkedin-api

It seems no matter what I try, I end up with this error. I have tried the default example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: YOUR_API_KEY_HERE
    authorize: true
    onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    // Setup an event listener to make an API call once auth is complete
    function onLinkedInLoad() {
       IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", getProfileData);
    }

    // Handle the successful return from the API call
    function onSuccess(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }

    // Handle an error response from the API call
    function onError(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }

    // Use the API call wrapper to request the member's basic profile data
    function getProfileData() {
      IN.API.Raw("/people/~:(firstName)?format=json").result(onSuccess).error(onError);
    }
</script>
```

I'm just trying to console log the first name of the user as a test. I have also tried various function names, as well as removing the `onLoad` argument just to test. I always get the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined.`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use `onLinkedInLoad` before it's defined, try swapping the `<script>` blocks order.